# Accepting inputs from Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to write a GUI in Tkinter that accepts a text inputs from the user and stores it in a variable `Text`; I also want to be able to use this variable later on... Here is something i tried that failed:

```
from Tkinter import *


def recieve():
    text = E1.get()
    return text

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack(side=LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd=5)

E1.pack(side=RIGHT)

b = Button(top, text="get", width=10, command=recieve)
b.pack()

print text

top.mainloop()
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
print text    
top.mainloop()
```

Before `top.mainloop()` is called, `text` has not been defined. Only after the call to `top.mainloop` is the user presented with the GUI interface, and the mainloop probably loops many many times before the user gets around to typing in the `Entry` box and pressing the `Button`. Only after the button is pressed is `recieve` (sic) called, and although it returns a value, that value is not stored anywhere after `recieve` ends. If you want to print `text`, you have to do it in the `recieve` function:

```
from Tkinter import *

def receive():
    text = E1.get()
    print(text)
top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
b = Button(top, text="get", width=10, command=receive)
b.pack()
top.mainloop()
```